# In Android, how to ensure that data are written to disk/flash?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-room

I am developing on an Android device (Android 10), which does not have battery. As such, it is affected by electricity going down and unplanned power off.

I have some critical sections in the solution, typically from sending a request to server till receiving and processing the response. If the restart of Android device occure inside this section, I need to detect this state and send activelly some rollback to the server.

Following the https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage, I am using

- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

### Shared preferences

I am using the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit() aproach, but I have produced the following scenario:

1. The `commit` function returns true as written, storing a flag (I can see this in logcat)
2. Sending the request to server as next step - logged
3. Reboot of the Android device
4. The flag from 1. is not written on read

### Room

Something similar happens for Room access - invoking the `insert` or `update` on Dao object, logging to logcat afterwards and going to reboot, data are not present in DB.

I am now trying, after invoking `insert` to `close` the DB and open it again before actually doing anything else. This seems to do the trick, but I am being concerned about performance, as the db will grow bigger.

### Question

What is the correct way, how to store flags and databases in a way, that they will be always written to disk/flash, before the functions returns? To be resistant to powerfailure at any time?

Comment: For testing I would use the most simplest interface: a file stream. Write something to it, flush it and close it. If that doesn't work then something is wrong with your OS reboot function. May be it does not properly shutdown the system but simply cut off power?

Comment: Yes, for testing - we are disconnecting and reconnecting directly the power cable, not an android reboot. Using directly files is an idea, but in that case, we will need to write _preferences_ and _database_ mechanism ourself...

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with shared prefs or room, but if you write to a file directly, then I believe you can run [FileDescriptor.sync()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#sync()) to ensure changes were written to the physical drive.